Why is "reckon" transitive in "to reckon to finish by ten" and "to reckon to pay so much"?
In Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, the entry for "reckon" at sense 3 marks the verb as transitive with two examples as follows:


We reckon to finish by ten.
He wasn’t reckoning to pay so much.


However, both "finish" and "pay" in those two examples are intransitive. So, I can't see for myself how "reckon" can be transitive?

Although the dictionary will list your examples a "transitive", they don't actually feature a noun a the "object" (as in A skinflint reckons every penny). Your examples have a [verb-based] clause as the "object" (complement), in which context it's irrelevant whether the verb in the complement is 1) transitive (I reckon he killed her) or 2) intransitive (I reckon she is dead). Dictionaries and grammarians will classify reckon as "transitive" in both my examples, even though only the first features a transitive verb in the complement.

@FumbleFingers, In your examples, isn't "reckon" in both "I reckon he killed her" and "I reckon she is dead" transitive?

The transitive quality of reckon doesn't depend on other verbs. Anyway, picture the examples as We reckon "to finish by ten" and He wasn’t reckoning "to pay so much." When we reckon, we are using a rough calculation. How long to finish? I reckon ten. I reckon by ten. I reckon before ten, but might take longer.

Hi, Tran Khanh, yes, reckon is transitive in both examples in @FumbleFingers' comments. Although the verb in the complement of the second example she is dead is intransitive,
that doesn't affect the transitivity of the  verb  reckon of the matrix clause.

In old-school grammar a transitive verb was one that took a noun-phrase as direct object. I reckon that it is  not unreasonable to extend that definition to include clause types that have nominal status, like infinitival clauses and declarative and interrogative content clauses, if you think that is better than calling those clauses complements.

I add to what @FumbleFingers said.
In a construction reckon to do something, as in We reckon to finish by ten, reckon is transitive; the matrix clause verb head has
the nonfinite infinitive clause to finish by ten as its complement. The transitivity of any verbs in the complement is immaterial, that is, whether finish in to finish by ten is transitive is immaterial.
This applies also to the other example.

Interestingly, it's perfectly natural for at least some speakers to respond to a question such as "Do you think it's time to go?" with "I reckon". I'm not really interested in fitting terminology to "awkward" cases, because so far as I know, both "I reckon" and "I reckon so" are valid "intransitive" responses in that context, whereas the semantically identical "I reckon it is" is "transitive". At that point, I'm not convinced the distinction is useful.
